# How to create Application.exe.config in application directory

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, configuration-files

So I recently updated my application to support a new feature.  In the past if the configuration file was deleted by the user it wasn't a big deal.  This new feature requires it to exist, and one of the requirements is that, the file exists in the application's installation directory.

I have notice when the file is deleted ( depending on variables I have not figured out ) I get a .NET notification that the configuration file is missing or corrupt.  Currently my program then crashes ( I still have to figure out how to duplicate this behavior ) which is the reason for this question.

I am familar with ConfigurationManager.  I am having trouble writting the file once the default values are loaded.  Forcing a Save for some reason does not seem to recreate the file, at least not in the installation directory, which is a requirement.

I am looking for guidence on how to handle this corner case in an elegant manner.  I would post code, honestly its just all failed attempts, which while my attempts do generate a file the contents are not the settings I am looking for.

I am willing to post anything that might be able to help.

Comment: Ask your user to instead delete the .exe file from now on.  Easier to support.  Kidding aside, trying to support a user that willfully deletes files is pointless.  They'll figure out to stop doing that after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using the built-in config support and just use write/read to a file called something.exe.config using the standard XML classes and if that gets deleted, just re-create it from values hard-coded in the executable.

The config file support is supposed to make things easier, if you need to do stuff where it makes things difficult, don't use it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Sorry for the late reply but I missed this comment. Your comment doesn't actually make any difference though. Keep using the same config file, but stop using the built in classes to read/write to it. Just use it as a normal XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

var wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
Configuration newConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
newConfig.Save();

doesn't work?

Comment: No. Applications normally CAN NOT WRITE INTO THEIR DIRECTORY - and the user makes clear (application.EXE.config) he is not talking of the web.config here.

Comment: I originally tried ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration( ConfigurationUserLevel.None ) I then attempted to add a new setting, the outcome was a file that contained the single new entry.

Answer (score 0):

You dont. Under normal conditions the program can not write into it's install directory - this is a standard windows security issue and the reason why app application data should reside ni external (from the exe's point) driectories.

If an admin deletes the config file, crash, ask for reinstall. There is nothing you can RELIABLY do, as you can not assume you can write into the folder at runtime. A message followed by an event log entry is the best approach here. Users are not supposed to delete parts of the application.

Comment: No. It is not. The directory is write protected normally for the application and the user. That simple. I suggest you read up the guidelines how windows apps shuold behave - it is explained very well in there.

Comment: not fine. you can not put it anywhere else. The Application.exe.config HAS TO BE IN THE SAME FOLDER. Otherwise - dont use it. Use your own cnofiguartion file and put it somewhere else (as per guidelines). And SHUT UP telling me not to provide non helping answer WHEN THERE IS NONE. Reality does NOT bunge to your requirements. ERality is real. If there IS NO SOLUTION THEN THERE IS NONE, live with it. If possible dont use the config file, use your own somewhere else (there isa  folder for that). Sadly that is not always possible.

Comment: SO you tell suers to modify the security settings on the program files folder or your application subfolder, or is it not protected on your computer because you run as administrator?