# C# creating a log file if application.exe.config is missing at launch

Tags: c#, file, logging, config

I'm trying to figure out how to inform the user that the app crashed because of a missing config file. I could use

```
 if (!File.Exists("application.exe.config")) 
   { 
     CreateLaunchErrorLog("Message...."); 
     Environment.Exit(0); 
   }
```

but the application crashes before the Main method. Any way around to get this to work?

The config file is intended to be modified by the user.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is crashing prior to main *because* of the missing config file, you might want to rethink how you are structuring your program.

For example, you may want to write a function that checks for the config and then loads all of its values, as the first function called from main or in a setup routine when the program loads.

This gives you the added benefit that besides displaying a message, you could recreate the file with reasonable defaults and then continue on with the rest of the program.

[These answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341228/how-to-create-application-exe-config-in-application-directory?rq=1) might help too.

Comment: I could configure VS to copy the original config file (application.config) to the ouput dir when compile and read from that file directly like I will do for any external files. In the second answer from the post you provide, it is mentioned that any data should reside outside the main app directory. So I discovered that I might not be able to modify my config file if in use by the application...which might bring me another issue. So I might have to rethink how to structure my program as you said.

Answer (score 1):

The application should not crash even if the configuration file does not exists unless the file is being used through code. Are you sure the config file or any app setting is not being called before?

Comment: The config file is used later on in Main method. But I verify its existence from the beginning.

Comment: Is it a console application. I created console application without default app.config file and it ran successfully. So, I don't think app is crashing before main method. Can you share stacktrace?

Comment: I restructured the main class and it works fine. I guess I was accidentally calling  the settings file from the global var. Thanks